# Errors compiling a program with travis ci/gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, travis-ci

There are so many errors that I dont even know what part of my code to post or where to fix the problem

Here is my code: https://github.com/dominique120/miniature-adventure

And this is the travis build log: https://travis-ci.org/dominique120/miniature-adventure/builds/21835584

This is the start of the error list:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/set:61:0,

from /home/travis/build/dominique120/miniature-adventure/src/npc.h:26,

from /home/travis/build/dominique120/miniature-adventure/src/game.h:32,

from /home/travis/build/dominique120/miniature-adventure/src/actions.cpp:27:

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_set.h:63:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘namespace’
/home/travis/build/dominique120/miniature-adventure/src/actions.cpp:575:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input

In file included from /home/travis/build/dominique120/miniature-adventure/src/game.h:31:0,
```

Comment: Did you try gcc 4.6 on your machine?

Comment: @lethal-guitar I get similar errors with MSVC(error about libraries) and no I have not tried on my machine yet.

Comment: Well I'd suppose try to get it working locally first, then try it again in Travis.

Comment: @lethal-guitar the problem is that I dont even know where to start. I cant even identify what the problem is.

Comment: Well, but nobody is going to read all your code and all your error messages and do it for you ;) Sometimes forgetting a `;` after a class declaration can cause errors like the ones you posted. Start by checking these